Regarding onehotencoder space cost
Why doesn't one-hot encoding use bit-based encoding? Wouldn't it take much less memory? What I mean is when you encode for example four cities you can do it like what one-hot encoder does by expanding one column to 4 or like this in one column:
    1st city = 0(base10) = 00000000
    2nd city = 1(base10) = 00000001
    3rd city = 2(base10) = 00000010
    4th city = 3(base10) = 00000011    

Isn't this just more efficient in terms of memory cost? Or does the encoding technique force it to take more space?

According to this answer, with the bit-based encoding, now the 2nd city and the 4th city share the feature x0, also the 3rd city and the 4th city share the feature x1, and it affects our predictions.

If there is already an answer to a question in Stack Overflow, there is no need to create a new answer, the question should be voted as duplicate.
